# $_POST always empty, $_GET works OK

Tags: php, post

I have a function that returns the request parameters for each request:

```
    private function GetRequestParams() {
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    switch (strtolower($method)) {
        case 'put':
            $this->requestParams = //parse_str(HttpResponse::getRequestBody())
            $this->requestParams = array_map('urldecode', $this->requestParams);
            break;
        case 'post':
            $this->requestParams = $_REQUEST;
            break;
        case 'get':
            $this->requestParams = $_GET;
            break;
        case 'delete':
            $this->requestParams = $_REQUEST;
            break;
        default:
            $this->requestParams = $_REQUEST;
    }
}
```

but when I call the same url with GET and POST, the $_POST parameters are empty. I use WizTools RestClient and the Apache Server from XAMPP tools to call the following url:
`http://localhost:80/project/?item=1`

For GET the request params correctly contain the "item", but for POST, the request params are empty.

It seems that the post method is correctly detected as the following function, sends correctly to postDescription() method:

`$method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) . 'Description';`

I have found an info to edit php.ini post_max_size = 8**M** to 8**MB** but that did not worked for me.

Comment: try an html form with method=post

Comment: why can't you use `$_REQUEST` here?

Comment: also, show the rest of your switch statement

Comment: Just checked and it works with $_REQUEST...However, I cannot figure out why $_POST is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_GET` is populated with data from the URL's query string.

`$_POST` is populated with data from the *post* message's body.

If you make a *post* request but pass the data in the query string, then the data will appear in `$_GET` not `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

$_POST is filled by HTML forms.  If you have a form and use method="POST" then the results from the form will be placed in POST.  Otherwise, if you use method="get" from forms OR use query strings (for example, index.php?foo=bar&this=that), then the results will be in $_GET.

Its generally safe to use $_REQUEST, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understanding why you'd be checking for both to begin with, but `$_GET` retrieves parameters sent in the URL (which is how you have it), whereas `$_POST` retrieves data "posted" to the server... usually through a form of some kind.

What's your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never use $_REQUEST as mentioned in some of the comments.

From http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

> ```
> Note: 
> The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET, POST,
> and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by the remote user
> and cannot be trusted.
> The presence and order of variables listed in this array is defined according
> to the PHP variables_order configuration directive.
> ```

And as Quentin already said in his answer, if you make a POST request the POST-Data has to be submitted in the body

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

> Name=Jonathan+Doe&Age=23&Formula=a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+13%25%21

Regards

Comment: Thanks all for help. I am trying to build a simple REST service that supports GET and POST and I was testing it. It seems that I was testing it wrong :). Thanks again.